# Different schedule on different days using Quartz Cron syntax

Tags: cron, databricks, workflow

I have a Databricks workflow that should run every hour, every day, from 4 am till 9 am, but on 15th of the month it should run from 1 am till 9 am instead.

Can I specify such a schedule using Quartz Cron syntax for a Databricks workflow?